Flutter CameraPreview is rotated 90 degrees
I've implemented a fairly simple camera page on my app, and I'm running into the issue of the camera preview behaving very strangely. Mainly, the preview seems to rotate the feed of the camera and stretches the content to fit the aspect ratio.
For example, when I'm taking a portrait it's supposed to be 4:3 aspect ratio, here it's rotated 90°, 3:4 ratio with everything stretched to fit that wrong aspect ratio.
Here is a picture from the android emulator (also tested on a real device)

Compared to the camera app in the emulator:

Here's a bit of code:
final controller = CameraController(
        _cameras.first,
        ResolutionPreset.ultraHigh,
        enableAudio: false,
      )
  ..lockCaptureOrientation(DeviceOrientation.portraitDown);
return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              flex: 7,
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CameraPreview(
                      controller,
                      key: const Key('CameraPreview'),
                    ),
...);

I'm using version 0.11.0+1 with flutter channel stable 3.22.1.
